# Haunted house movie that focuses on a basement door and a ghost who wants to steal a mother's child

Tags: story-identification, movie, ghost

I'm not 100%, but guessing 1960-1970s, maybe '80s at the latest.

I remember the movie focuses a lot on a mysterious basement door in a house. I want to say the door emitted the sound of an infant crying and maybe the door glowed. The spirit haunting the house wanted to steal the living mother's child. Pretty sure it is implied the spirit is a man who was an abusive father (could be wrong).

I remember a specific scene, which was the climax of the movie. The mother of the child and her little boy (I believe it was a son) are in the basement and there's either wind howling or the basement is flooded, trying to pull the kid out of her grasp. And I specifically remember her yelling something along the lines of:

> You can't have him! You KILLED your baby! You can't have mine!

I wanna say there's this roaring noise happening at the same time that may have been the spirit.

Trying to remember this from seeing it once when I was about 6 on TV; scared me for years. I was born in 1990, so I don't think the movie could have been made past 1995.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is ***[The Uninvited](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0141937/)*** (1996).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Uninvited_(1996_film)):

> *The Uninvited*, also known as *Victim of the Haunt*, *The Haunting of Patricia Johnson*, and *The House at the End of the Street*, is a 1996 made-for-TV film directed by Larry Shaw and starring Sharon Lawrence and Beau Bridges. Inspired by true events, the film was written by Karen Clark.

> **Inspired by true events. After Patti Johnson gives birth to a still-born child, she and her husband try to forget the tragedy. They move into a new house, but a number of supernatural phenomena that takes place there, lead them to believe that the house is haunted. Patti turns to the town psychic, who confirms her suspicions about ghostly activity. The house is haunted by the spirit of a man who, 75 years earlier, killed his young son and was then shot by his own wife, as well as by the spirit of the murdered son. And now the killer is after Patti's 3-year-old son, Jonathan.**

The plot summary above fits your description, and there's a climactic scene where a mother struggles to save her young son from being sucked into a glowing whirlpool in a basement. The ghostly face of an old man appears above the whirlpool, and the mother cries out:

> PATTIE JOHNSON: Leave him alone! You killed your son! You cannot have mine!
>
> <sub>*The Uninvited* (1996)</sub>

Comment: OH THANK YOU!! This is definitely the movie I was looking for! Thats 100% the climax I was remembering. | Though I think I was also conflating it with another film. There's heavy similarities here with something else I'm sure I watched as a kid. Cause I specifically remember the other film with a door that would have baby crying coming from it. I gotta see if I can find that one too.